# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { useContext } from 'react';

import AuthContext from '../contexts/AuthContext';

function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
    const auth = useContext(AuthContext);

    return(
        <Route
        {...rest}
        render={({ location }) => {
            auth.token ? (
                children
            ) : (
                <Redirect
                to={{
                    pathname: '/login',
                    state: { from: location },
            }}
          />
        )
      }} 
    />
  )
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions. What I did wrong

error in 13:13

```
  auth.token ? (
```

Comment: Your `render` function doesn't _return_ anything. The result of the conditional/ternary expression isn't assigned or returned.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the ternary operator.

```
return auth.token ? (
            children
        ) : (
            <Redirect
            to={{
                pathname: '/login',
                state: { from: location },
        }}
```